# pileup "]" meaning in read-bases column

Tags: bioinformatics, samtools

I have a pileup file from calling `samtools mpileup` and I'm confused to see a "]" in the column that shows read-base agreement with reference.

`1       861225  G       45      ............................................^]. ;JKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKFJ7FKKJKJKKKIKIJKKKKKHGJHE9`

Reading the [documentation](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-mpileup.html), I don't see mention of "]" as an option. Only "." "," and "atgc"